# How to support passing non-pointered value .use DLL,VARIANT

Tags: dll, go, variant

E.g:

//BmOpcDaClt_API BOOL _stdcall BMDACReadItem(DWORD ServerHandle,DWORD GroupHandle,DWORD ItemHandle,VARIANT* Value,FILETIME* pTimeStamp,WORD* pQuality)

```
var Value *ole.VARIANT
Value1 := ole.VARIANT{}
Value = &Value1

var pTimeStamp *w32.FILETIME
pTimeStamp1 := w32.FILETIME{}
pTimeStamp = &pTimeStamp1
var pQuality *uint16
var pQuality1 uint16 = 0
pQuality = &pQuality1

BMDAC_ReadItem.Call(uintptr(ConnectHandle), uintptr(GroupHandle), uintptr(ItemHandle), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(Value)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pTimeStamp)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pQuality)))
```

// this is ok!!!
//but

//BmOpcDaClt_API BOOL _stdcall BMDACWriteItem(DWORD ServerHandle,DWORD         GroupHandle,DWORD ItemHandle,VARIANT Value, BOOL DoAsync)

```
BMDAC_WriteItem.Call(uintptr(ConnectHandle), uintptr(GroupHandle), uintptr(ItemHandle), ????, uintptr(0))
```

//How to do ?

Comment: maybe ```uintptr(Value)```?

Comment: what happen by pass a VARIANT struct

Comment: I tried many times, not possible.